# split a four column html table into a two column one via css

Tags: html, css

I have a simple html `<table>` with four columns and I want to split it into two columns when the resolution is low via `@media`.

So what I found was the following code that put every td to an extra row.

```
td { display: block }
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
td:nth-child(odd)  { display: block }
```

Is there a way to split a row after every second td element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the cells to `inline-block` and `50%` width to achieve that, although setting `box-sizing: border-box` might be required if you have padding/borders in/around your cells, otherwise they will all wrap on separate rows!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid lightcoral;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  td {
    border-color: teal;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
    <td>Cell 4</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```